# Prove a function is pointwise convergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Prove the following function is pointwise convergent, and following this prove further whether or not it is uniformly convergent: $(e^{-nx^2})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$   $ (x\in\mathbb{R})$

I understand the definition of pointwise convergent, but Im just unsure how to use the definition to prove the convergence.

Set $\epsilon > 0$ then $f_n(x)=(e^{-nx^2})\rightarrow0$    $(n\rightarrow\infty$) to is pointwise convergent to $f(x)=0$

For $n\neq0$ $|f_n(n)-f(n)|=|e^{-nn^2}|=|e^{-n^3}|\rightarrow 0$

For $n=0 |f_n(n)-f(n)|=|e^{-nn^2}|=|e^0|\rightarrow 1$

Therefore as the limit function is not continuous it is not uniformly convergent
Is this proof correct?

Comment: Show that for fixed $x\neq 0$ you have $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-nx^2}=0$ What's for $x=0$? Why does this contradict uniform convergence?

Comment: @sigmabe I have edited my post, is this now correct?

Comment: Why are you looking at $f_n(n)$? You need the convergence for ever $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x_n \to \infty$ then $e^{-x_n} \to 0$. Now if $x\neq 0$ then $nx^2 \to \infty$ and $e^{-nx^2} \to 0$. If $x=0$ then $nx=0 \forall n$ and $e^{-nx^2}=1$ does not change. Out of this it follows that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} e^{-nx^2}$ converges as $n\to \infty$ to some number. This is the statement that the sequence of functions $e^{-nx^2}$ converges pointwise to another function, in this case to the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}0 \quad x\neq 0\\1 \quad x=0\end{cases}$.

Since $e^{-nx^2}$ is continuous for all $n$ but the limit is not, the sequence does not converge uniformly. (As the uniform limit of continuous functions is again continuous).